# Strange error from laravel Backend REST API request

Tags: laravel-5

I make @vue/cli 4.0.5 / vuex 3 app with data reading from Laravel 5.8 Backend REST API app

I uploaded my app on Ubuntu server (Digital Ocean) about 2 weeks ago and today I found that my app does not work
as all requests to my Backend REST API app returns message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>

<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel=icon href=/images/favicon.ico>
    <title id=app_title>V Tasks</title>
    <link href=/css/about.8b7fdd6b.css rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/css/chunk-54032134.53235256.css rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/about.10ed4f34.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-2d0c7e58.d06a9dfa.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-2d0e5060.180cdb07.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-2d0e5e97.5e310a93.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-396ee539.e39580f6.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-54032134.35996136.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-7e2da331.e5adb838.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-8bcf2014.e2eb781b.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/js/chunk-eda59d9a.5e7ed3f8.js rel=prefetch>
    <link href=/css/app.355f43b3.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.377ce48f.css rel=preload as=style>
    <link href=/js/app.9d2d5593.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/js/chunk-vendors.7429debf.js rel=preload as=script>
    <link href=/css/chunk-vendors.377ce48f.css rel=stylesheet>
    <link href=/css/app.355f43b3.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>

<body><noscript><strong>We're sorry but vtasks doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong></noscript>
    <div id=app></div>
    <script src=/js/chunk-vendors.7429debf.js></script>
    <script src=/js/app.9d2d5593.js></script>
</body>

</html>
```

That is not issue of my browsers. I tested several: tghe same returns.
My local vervion (apache hostings) works ok

What could cause this error and how to fix it?

**UPDATE BLOCK:**
As that is Laravel 5.8 Backend REST API app I removed welcome route in routes/web.php file
and tried to run app root at
http://vtasks-backend.my-demo-apps.tk/
and works ok

But in console of my app I see error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJdhv.jpg
Could ypou please try from your side? What do you see?

It worked yesterday without any problems, but today I see these errors and I do not see why and how to fix it...
I did not modfify any configurations...
On this server there are several my app and now they all works ok.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message "We're sorry but vtasks doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue." is in <noscript> tags. Is Javascript disabled for your browser?

Comment: Yes, Javascript is enabled in all my browsers. Also I check : my local version of the app works ok. That is request from  Laravel 5.8 Backend REST API app...

Comment: Could you please run my app in your browser : http://vtasks.my-demo-apps.tk/  Also ps check in console request to server

Comment: Did you try. What do you see in your browser's console ?

Comment: pls look UPDATE BLOCK

Comment: I looked at it, seems ok. Try a hard refresh (Ctrl + Shift + R).

Comment: No for (Ctrl + Shift + R - the same problems. Could you please send printscreen of the page and console ?

Comment: Sorry, very stuped of me, I set rest api server my client app root